# Build HTML link to email address

Tags: javascript, object

If I have this object literal:

```
{"name":"James","email":"123@yahoo.com"}
```

... how do I print out an HTML link to that email address? The output should be something like this:

```
<a href="mailto:123@yahoo.com">James</a>
```

Comment: Would you like to use plain javascript, jquery, or something else? Or is this happening server-side?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
var contact = {"name": "James", "email":"123@yahoo.com"};
var href = "mailto:" + contact.email;

var link = document.createElement('a');

link.setAttribute("href", href);
link.innerHTML = contact.name;

document.body.appendChild(link);
```

http://jsbin.com/qimosu/1/